# How can I add Dictionary Object dynamically in LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

```
var topLevel = resultRows.GroupBy(g => g["CustomerAccountType"])
            .Select(cat => new Dictionary<string, object>
{
      {"AccountGroupName", cat.First()["CustomerAccountType"] },
      {"Actual1" , cat.Sum(s => Convert.ToDecimal(s["Actual1"])) },
      {"Actual2" , cat.Sum(s => Convert.ToDecimal(s["Actual2"])) },
      {"Actual3" , cat.Sum(s => Convert.ToDecimal(s["Actual3"])) },
      {"Actual4" , cat.Sum(s => Convert.ToDecimal(s["Actual4"])) },
      {"Actual5" , cat.Sum(s => Convert.ToDecimal(s["Actual5"])) },
      {"Actual6" , cat.Sum(s => Convert.ToDecimal(s["Actual6"])) },
      {"Actual7" , cat.Sum(s => Convert.ToDecimal(s["Actual7"])) },
      {"Actual8" , cat.Sum(s => Convert.ToDecimal(s["Actual8"])) },
      {"Actual9" , cat.Sum(s => Convert.ToDecimal(s["Actual9"])) },
      {"Actual10" , cat.Sum(s => Convert.ToDecimal(s["Actual10"])) },
      {"Actual11" , cat.Sum(s => Convert.ToDecimal(s["Actual11"])) },
      {"Actual12" , cat.Sum(s => Convert.ToDecimal(s["Actual12"])) }
 });
```

I want to add "Actual 1 to 10 dynamically in above dictionary either by index or iteration.

Comment: The title asks about a dictionary but the code looks like you are trying to pivot a DataTable. What are you trying to do?

Comment: It's not a DataTable. resultRows came from OLAP cubes which I added as Dictionary and now I'm trying to Make Hierarchical collection object out of Keys. But I want to eliminate reduntant ActualN...ActuanN and replace it with iteration or something to index keys that StartsWith("Actual')

Comment: Please describe the problem you are trying to solve, not how you expect to solve it. What you describe is similar to SQL Server's UNPIVOT operator applied to the group result. BTW why are you calculating the Sum? An OLAP cube should be able to return the measure sums for each account type. Unpivoting account type rows is easier than unpivoting the detail rows

Comment: Instead of typing ActualN repeatedly, I want to iterate the collection and add Keys that startsWith "Actual" dynamically. The reason is that ActualN is not known until runtime. (There might  be Actual13, Actual14 etc depending on the cubes tabular output) The code above works if done statically. The SUM are for Rolled up total required to be displayed as Hierarchy total in a Tree like view control.

Comment: Got an answer here....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27595452/how-can-i-get-selected-column-into-a-dictionary

Answer (score 3):

LINQ provides the [Enumerable.ToDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548554(v=vs.100).aspx) method to create a Dictionary form a query's results, eg:

```
var dict=myQuery.ToDictionary(item=>item.KeyProperty,item=>item.ValueProperty);
```

Comment: What I want to do is eliminate redundant ActualN and replace it with dictionary<string,object>()

Comment: In simple terms. I want to Select a dictionary of object without hardcoding ActualN....ActualN. like the code above. I need a proper lambda expression for that. The given collection object is resultRows

Comment: Note that `ToDictionary` can take explicit type arguments, and lambdas do allow for type-casting.

Answer (score 0):

It will be like this:

```
var q1 = resultRows.GroupBy(g => g["CustomerAccountType"]);

    var toLevel = q1
        .Where(g => g.Key != "CustomerAccountType")
        .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => (object)g.Sum(s => Convert.ToDecimal(s[g.Key])));

        toLevel.Add("AccountGroupName", q1
        .First(g => g.Key == "CustomerAccountType").Select(f => f["CustomerAccountType"]));
```

Comment: This is close to what I need but there is a syntax error "Cannot convert lamba expression to type'System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer<object>' because it is not a delegate type

Comment: I do not have a strongly typed object by the way because the collection will be dynamic

Comment: I Compiled that with this on definition: var resultRows = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();

Comment: Do you think you can do necessary tweaks for your dynamic collection?

Comment: Exactly. here is my variable declaration 

List<Dictionary<string, object>> resultRows = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();

Comment: If you give me your expected dynamic type resultRows I can fix that for you.

Comment: I created a complete gist on github https://gist.github.com/agentpx/f34de8fac56bba1e2f67

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67244/discussion-between-tommymoore-and-agentpx).