# How can I get selected column into a Dictionary?

Tags: c#, linq

```
var topLevel= resultRows.GroupBy(g => g["CustomerAccountType"]);
```

I want to select columns only like `Actual1`, `Actual2`, `Actual3`, etc. The names of the columns are not known upfront - they are composed dynamically.

I am not using a strongly type object because resultsRows is a constructed Dictionary from SQL cubes.

I want to dynamically add ActualN...to..ActualN to a collection as dictionary.

Comment: What keys / values do you want in your dictionary? It's really not clear from your question...

Comment: Dashblinkenlight understand my question and provided a solution below. Thanks to him who does not down vote my question but edited it. A 300k reputation show's why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Select` to make a projection of `Actual1, Actual2, Actual3`:

```
var topLevel= resultRows
    .Select(d => new Dictionary<string,object> {
        {"Actual1", d["Actual1"]}
    ,   {"Actual2", d["Actual2"]}
    ,   {"Actual3", d["Actual3"]}
    });
```

This will remove all columns other than `Actual1, Actual2, Actual3` from your dictionary.

> I want `Actual1` to `ActualN` added dynamically without knowing how many are there

You can do that, too:

```
// Construct this list dynamically
var selection = new List<string> {
    "Actual1", "Actual2", ..., "ActualN"
};
var topLevel= resultRows.Select(d => selection.ToDictionary(s => s, s => d[s]));
```

Comment: Sorry my question is not clear. Yes I can do that. I want actual1...to...ActualN added dynamically without knowing how many are there.

Comment: dasblinkenlight I know now why you are 300k in reputation :D